# simplify an expression of vectors an matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to simplify this term where:

1. s is a n x 1 vector
2. z and z' are a n x 1 vector
3. and D is a n x n matrix

I know that by changing the place of a matrix inside the multiplication will mess up the result. For example, can i multiply by s the whole equation so the 1/s will go away? or use z as a common factor? essentially what rules can i follow in these type of equations that they won't break them?

$$
\frac{1}{s} * z' = \frac{1}{s} * z - \frac{1}{1+ tr(D*\frac{1}{s}*z)}*\frac{1}{s}*z*D*\frac{1}{s}*z
$$

Comment: what is $1/s$? and what operation is $*$ ?

Comment: 1/s is the fraction that has the s vector in the denominator and  the operation is a cross product

Comment: What the watermelon is a fraction with a vector denominator? What does it returns? another vector? Is it an element-wise operation? And in that case, how do you define the cross product between a matrix and a vector?